# Is there any other way except forms to POST and redirect simultaneously in django?

Tags: python, django, post

Basically, what I'm asking is - is it possible to perform a POST request like form submit without using the form submit. 
Something like:

```
data = {'name':'John Doe', 'age':30}
post_data_to_url('www.example.com',post_data = data)
```

and then it redirects to `www.example.com` with POSTed data.

And I did checkout the Python `requests` package but it doesn't seem to redirect, just gets the response headers. Or am I missing something ?

Sorry if I'm still unclear. Here's an example:

```
def some_view(request):
    data = {'Amt':200, 'taxAmt':20,'tAmt':220}
    url = 'www.example.com/payment'
    resp = requests.post(url, data)
    return some_template
```

Now, when the part `requests.post(url,data)` runs, I expect to be redirected to the page `www.example.com/payment` and this is not my server. Say it's some remote payment gateway server like Paypal.

Comment: Your questions is a little unclear to me. The client/browser doesn't redirect. The server is the one that issues redirects. And then the client/browser goes to the redirected page. Basically, a redirect is a response sent by the server to the client to navigate to a certain page.

Comment: I'm asking if anything similar to form submission exists in server side ? Sending data with POST request to another server ?

Comment: The `requests` library automatically follows redirects. It's documented: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

Comment: Well, I can't seem to be able to make myself redirect to another server page with `requests`. The data is posted and I get a response code 200 and other headers but I want to be landed on the actual server page- that's what I meant by redirection. How do you do that ?

Comment: That is still unclear. What does "landed on the actual server page" mean? And if the server returns 200, then it isn't sending a redirect anyway.

Comment: I've edited the question to add an example.  I want to do exactly what the form does on the client side, submit data with a POST method.